# Sqlalchemy results post-processing

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm fetching a dataset from my database with sqlalchemy in Python :

```
links = session.query(Link).order_by(Link.id.desc()).limit(20)
```

I'm then iterating over the `links` result in my view :

```
%for link in links:
    <div class="link">
        {{link.url}}
        %if link.pdf: 
            <a href="{{link.pdf}}">[pdf]</a>
        %end
    </div>
%end
```

I want to read the external attribute in `link`, `pdf` if a pdf file exists for the result.

I've tried :

```
for index, link in enumerate(links):
    if os.path.isfile('/pdf/'+str(link.id)+'.pdf'):
        links[index].pdf = '/pdf/'+str(link.id)+'.pdf'
    else:
        links[index].pdf = None
```

but the `pdf` attribute is apparently not set.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a python property should probably do the job, e.g.

```
class Link(Base):
    ...

    @property
    def pdf(self):
        path = '/pdf/%d.pdf' % self.id
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            return path
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd create a list of mappings with the information needed:

```
linkinfo = []
for link in links:
    pdf = '/pdf/'+str(link.id)+'.pdf'
    pdf = pdf if os.path.isfile(pdf) else None
    linkinfo.append({'url': link.url, 'pdf': pdf})
```

then loop over the `linkinfo` list in your template instead.

This saves having to hassle with SQLAlchemy objects and makes sure your template is handed all the right data for display.